# Exchange: Sending out Meeting cancellations even if meeting is in the past

Tags: outlook, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

For my code to run I need to fetch all the meeting cancellations from a shared mailbox.

I just discovered, those meeting cancellations are only send by the respective outlook client, when the meeting, which is about to be cancelled, is in the future. If the meeting is in the past, it is just deleted from the organizers mailbox and remains in the mailboxes from all other attendees.

Is there any option on the exchange server or outlook client, which allows me to have the organizer send a meeting cancellation message to all attendees, even if the meeting is in the past?

We're using Exchange Server 2013.